# How to print boldface iteration in algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

How to print boldface "Iteration:" in the algorithm as shown in the picture below? As in document, I don't think I find any description about the command of iteration.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmiciteration}{\textbf{Iteration:}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\floatc@ruled}[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1:} #2\par}
\algnewcommand\Iteration{%
    \algpx@endCodeCommand%
    \ifnumcomp{0}{<}{\FSSize{algpx@startNewCodeBoxQueue}}{\setbool{algpx@setNorth}{true}}{}%
    \algpx@drawInItem{\algorithmiciteration}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{title}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require $x \in \{0,1\}$
\Iteration $y \in \{1,2\}$
\State $y \gets x+1$
\State \Return $y$
\Ensure $y \in \{1,2\}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really thanks! I will try!

Comment: Just modify the definition of `\Ensure` in `algpseudocodex.sty`.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Sorry that I am not familiar with the use of algorithm in latex.

Comment: If the answer meets your needs, you can accept it.